# PHP - Best login system method

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask you, what's the best method to create login system with php :

1. Store DATA into `$_SESSION` variable and in database for authentication
2. Or store DATA into `$_COOKIE` variable ?

Which is the best method ?

I ask it for `Remember my password feature` !

Comment: Cookie is the way to go

Comment: Remember password for how long? Session variables are lost when the user closes the browser so this should give you a clue

Comment: The problem is not saving in $_SESSION or $_COOKIE, but, how you save data and how to deal with user session, considering session or cookie hijacking, implementing secure tokens or captcha...

Comment: If you are just concerned with `Remember My Password` feature then you must go for `Cookie` option. It is the best way to go. But `save the password by encrypting` it.

Comment: @F4r-20 Hi this is Dead man again. We again meet in a question that got closed lolzzzzz :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Remember me` facility than you have to store information in browser's cookie.

password must be in encryption.

Comment: @DarkCthulhu yah you are right

Comment: yOU smart, agree !,  But why my question was closed. i want to share my knowledge here ... with answering my own question !! Huhhh :C

Comment: @MichaelAntonius Questions like these are usually closed. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask.

Comment: @MichaelAntonius you can answer here in comment